# Share song on WhatsApp, always ends in "failed to send" message

Tags: android

I'm getting an input stream from a webservice and converting it to byte array so i can create a temporary file and play it using MediaPlayer (it is a .mp3). The problem is that i want to share the song on whatsapp, but i get the "failed to send" message whenever i try.

This is how i get and play the song:

```
if (response.body() != null) {
   byte[] bytes = new byte[0];
   try {
      bytes = toByteArray(response.body().byteStream());
   } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }

mediaPlayer.reset();
try {
     File tempMp3 = File.createTempFile("tempfile", "mp3", getContext().getCacheDir());
     tempMp3.deleteOnExit();
     FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempMp3);
     fos.write(mp3);
     fos.close();

     FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(tempMp3);

     mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fis.getFD());
     mediaPlayer.prepare();
}
catch (IOException ex) {
     String s = ex.toString();
     ex.printStackTrace();
}

mediaPlayer.start();
```

This and a few similar ways is how i have tried to share it:

```
String sharePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                    + "/tempfile.mp3";
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(sharePath);
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("audio/*");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound File"));
```

The song is playing just fine and i have included the permission both for reading and writing in the external storage but i need help to share the song, be it as bytes or as file or as whatever works, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to change from

```
File tempMp3 = File.createTempFile("tempfile", "mp3", getContext().getCacheDir());
```

to

```
File tempMp3 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"+ getString(R.string.temp_file) + getString(R.string.dot_mp3)); //<- this is "tempfile" and ".mp3"
```

then you can share it like this

```
String sharePath = tempMp3.getAbsolutePath();
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(sharePath);
        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("audio/*");
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, getString(R.string.share_song_file)));
```

The main problem was that where you were storing the file could NOT be shared with other apps, was only accessible from your own, since the getCacheDir() method is used to create cache files rather than storing data in files persistently, and is sort of private to the application (and createTempFile() generates random numbers at the end of the file's name, so you wouldn't be able to hard code the correct path like that).
Also, this solution makes use of the permissions you included (accessing external storage).